# Is a single return statement cleaner?

Tags: c++

Today, me and my colleague have a disagreement on a subject :

Which of the following is "cleaner" and why ? :

```
bool check(){
    if(!test to do){
        return false;
    }
    if(!other test to do){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or:

```
bool check(){
    bool result = true;
    if(!test to do){
        result =  false;
    }
    if(!other test to do){
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In my opinion, it doesn't matter because of compilation process.

Comment: There are the one, which like early bail-outs. There are the other which think, there should be only one `return` at end of function. I'm even my-self not clear what I like more... (I.e. sounds a bit like asking for opinions.)

Comment: @Vlad: We can only reason about the code presented, not some other hypothetical code that does something entirely different. You claimed that the snippets presented are not functionally equivalent, which is not true. (Except that I am again assuming there are no side effects :P)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think that the question is about whether to use one return statement or several return statements. Presented examples are not very correct. The second if statement in the second code snippet in general shall include a test of the variable result in the condition.

Comment: Sadly this was closed as opinion based. That's fine so long as the opinion is the same as mine, which is the correct one. Dogmatists favour the second way since they argue it's easier to debug (forgetting of course that exceptions also play around with linear program control flow). The first way is better all round. If `other test to do` throws an exception or is somehow contingent on the result of `test to do` then the results are potentially different. An `else` before the second `if` in the second snippet yields equivalence for all cases where the return type is not subject to copy elision.

Comment: My personal opinion is that extra returns are fine at either the start or the end of a method. If the method has other work to do and starts returning randomly it can be very difficult to follow; but when handling precondition failures at the start, or quantifying return codes at the end early returns keep the code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

It *almost* doesn't matter functionally, because of the compilation process.

Some older texts recommend a *single* `return`, i.e. your second example, as they say the logic of the function is easier to trace.

Personally I dislike clutter and find the first example easier to read. You still have to think about and reason about the function in either case, just the first doesn't involve an additional variable and potentially more `if`/`else` flow clutter.

The first one doesn't always evaluate the second condition, though, which may be of interest to you if it has performance penalties, or side effects.

Furthermore, individual return statements are easier for the compiler to elide (not that it matters here).

But otherwise it's completely subjective.

Comment: what about copy elision?  Multiple returns ensure that the compiler can always do this.  Having a single return I suspect will result in cases where the optimisation can not be done?   (though obviously not applicable for the given trivial boolean example)

Comment: @UKMonkey Possibly!